# Why can't I use ENV variables with Firebase functions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, gcloud-node

Why can't I use env variables as I would with Google Cloud Functions? As I understand, Firebase functions sit on top of Google Cloud. With Firebase functions you can use environment configuration but is not the same.

I have done both implementations but I find it easier to work with environment variables with google cloud functions.

Maybe I just don't know how to do it and I can't find any documentation, so if someone can point me in the right direction I will appreciate it. If there are any advantages of doing it the firebase functions way let me know.

[Google cloud functions env docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/env-var)

[Firebase functions config env docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/config-env)

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase CLI manages the process environment variables for deployed functions.  It does not offer a way to change or override that management, other than modifying its [source code](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools) to do what you want.

Comment: Is it possible to use gcloud cli to deploy firebase functions?

Comment: I won't say that it's *impossible*, but I think you'll have a very hard time making this happen - it's not a supported option.

Comment: Any particular reason why they would need to work differently. Is just that the firebase approach seems odd to me

Comment: It was a decision that the Firebase team made.  If you want to send feedback to the Firebase team, please go through Firebase support.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Answer (score -1):

To store environment data for Firebase functions, you can use the `firebase functions:config:set` command in the Firebase CLI. Each key can be namespaced using periods to group related configuration together. Keep in mind that only lowercase characters are accepted in keys; uppercase characters are not allowed.

For instance, to store the Client ID and API key for "Some Service", you might run:

```
firebase functions:config:set someservice.key="THE API KEY" someservice.id="THE CLIENT ID"
```

To inspect what's currently stored in environment config for your project, you can use `firebase functions:config:get`. It will output JSON something like this:

```
{
  "someservice": {
    "key":"THE API KEY",
    "id":"THE CLIENT ID"
  }
}
```

Comment: this is not what Im asking